# How to attach PVC pipe to 1-1/4" metal/lead pipe

Tags: plumbing, pvc

I'm trying to attach this sink trap to the wall drain which appears to be an old metal/lead pipe. The old trap was attached using a flex rubber coupling, but because it's not a shielded one, it is not up to code.

I have not been able to find a shielded 1-1/4 inch rubber coupling anywhere. Stores or online. So that would be an ideal solution, but it doesn't appear there is one.

So next I found this PVC adapter which can attach to the metal pipe, but I'm not sure if the compression of the rubber washer would be enough to prevent water from leaking OR if this is up to code either.

Any suggestions?  I could use 1-1/4 or 1-1/2 trap PVC lines but the wall pipe is 1-1/4 so I'm limited to that attachment at the wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be shielded?  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fernco-1-1-2-in-x-1-1-4-in-DWV-Flexible-PVC-Coupling-P1056-150-125/100044154

Comment: @AlaskaMan yes it has to be shielded in order to pass inspections here.

Comment: Call Fernco and see if they can direct you.  https://www.fernco.com/contact-us

Comment: The way that pipe is degraded I'd be pulling out all the stops to replace it to a more substantial point. I can see it just crushing under the strain of a clamp.

Comment: @isherwood I was thinking about doing that too but I'm not sure how those old lead pipes are connected or if I'd be opening a can of worms doing that. I'm just kinda dumbfounded how there is not a 1 1/4 inch shielded coupling.

Comment: 1-1/4" pipe hasn't been legal for a very long time. Any work done (as in your case) almost invariably involves an upgrade to the branch to at least 1-1/2". Get out your can opener.